# Помогите упростить функцию

Tags: java

Помогите упростить функцию `drawRect(int w, int h);`. Понимаю, костыли за костылями, но на ошибках учатся. Мне важны какие то специальные методы для упрощения.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void drawRect(int w, int h) {
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                System.out.print("╔");
            else if (i == (w - 1))
                System.out.print("╗");
            else
                System.out.print("═");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {

            if (i != h - 1) {
                System.out.print("║");
                for (int j = 0; j < (w - 2); j++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println("║");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("╚");
                for (int j = 0; j < (w - 2); j++) {
                    System.out.print("═");
                }
                System.out.println("╝");
                }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawRect(30, 10);
    }

}
```

На выходе рисует

```
╔════════════════════════════╗
║                            ║
║                            ║
║                            ║
║                            ║
║                            ║
║                            ║
║                            ║
║                            ║
║                            ║
╚════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: В каком плане "специальные методы"? Тут другой идеи в принципе нет, разве что это можно записать короче

Comment: Я боюсь меня учитель отшлепает (((((

Comment: Ха, да точно...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В примитивном виде:

```
public static String stringRepeat(String str, int times) {
    return new String(new char[times]).replace("\0", str);
}

public static void drawRect(int w, int h) {
    System.out.print("╔");
    System.out.print(stringRepeat("=", w - 2));
    System.out.println("╗");

    for (int i = 0; i < h - 2; i++) {
        System.out.print("║");
        System.out.print(stringRepeat(" ", w - 2 ));
        System.out.println("║");
    }

    System.out.print("╚");
    System.out.print(stringRepeat("=", w - 2));
    System.out.println("╝");
}
```

Далее вместо множества `System.out` можно загонять с помощью `StringBuilder` в отдельную переменную и в конце вывести

---

Для string.repeat можно использовать [apache StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Comment: А вот про stringRepeat спасибо

Comment: @Duoxx кстати, забыл, что надо `h - 2` тоже писать. а оптимизацией и проверками уж сами

Comment: https://ideone.com/7vVJug

Answer (score 3):

Я бы завёл матрицу символов, которую бы сначала заполнил, а потом вывел. Это будет дольше работать и требует дополнительной памяти (и кода, возможно, получится больше), но зато, как мне кажется, это гораздо понятней и поддерживать такой код проще.

[Код на ideone](https://ideone.com/GhAnOr).

```
public class Main {
    public static void drawRect(int w, int h) {
        char[][] matrix = new char[h][w];

        // углы
        matrix[    0][    0] = '╔';
        matrix[    0][w - 1] = '╗';
        matrix[h - 1][    0] = '╚';
        matrix[h - 1][w - 1] = '╝';

        // левая и правая сторона
        for (int i = 1; i < h - 1; ++i) {
            matrix[i][    0] = '║';
            matrix[i][w - 1] = '║';
        }

        // левая и правая сторона
        for (int j = 1; j < w - 1; ++j) {
            matrix[    0][j] = '═';
            matrix[h - 1][j] = '═';
        }

        // пробелы
        for (int i = 1; i < h - 1; ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j < w - 1; ++j) {
                matrix[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }

        // вывод
        for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        drawRect(30, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно вынести лишние проверки из циклов, а также объявить пару констант: ширину и высоту.

```
public static void drawRect(int w, int h) {
    final int width = w - 2;
    final int height = h - 2;

    System.out.print("╔");
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        System.out.print("═");
    }
    System.out.println("╗");

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        System.out.print("║");
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("║");
    }

    System.out.print("╚");
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        System.out.print("═");
    }
    System.out.println("╝");
}
```

Также можно вынести в отдельные функции рисование верхней/средней и нижней линий.